# JOGL - does OpenGL use the AWT thread to render graphics?

Tags: multithreading, opengl, rendering, awt, jogl

I am making a simple program with Java OpenGL (jogl). In the display() method I am printing the name of the thread and the output says it is the AWT thread. Doesn't OpenGL use its own thread?

Comment: I think JOGL uses an AWT Frame to render stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly it depends on the version you are using.

For the early version 1.0 and 1.1 jogl used a different thread for the rendering by default.
For version 1.1.1 it was switched to default to using the AWT thread.

This can be manually controlled from the command line using `-Djogl.1thread=true` to force single threaded rendering on the AWT thread or `-Djogl.1thread=false` to force multi threaded rendering (one per canvas) outside of the AWT thread.

Newer version of Jogl provide a custom toolkit called NEWT that will perform rendering outside of the AWT thread.

The Jogl 1.0/1.1.1 threading behaviour is described here: http://download.java.net/media/jogl/doc/userguide/ in the section "Multithreading Issues"

More information on NEWT threading can be found here: http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/NEWT-Overview.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL libraries work by hooking into the native java Display and a generic frame. You can create a new canvas in the AWT thread and then create a new thread for Display, setting the new canvas as the displayparent within the new thread, and the display will not run in the AWT thread.